# Aviarc workflow error "CommandException: If condition did not produce a Boolean value: getArgument returned 1"

Tags: aviarc

The error occurs on this if statement:

```xml
<if test="equal" value1="{$m.parent_id}" value2="{$var.tasks-menu-id}">
    <math:increment field="var.tasks-children"/>
</if>
```

I've double checked that the dataset field references are returning the correct value, and the test should work even if one or both of the values are null.

Answer (score 0):

The "If condition did not produce a Boolean value" error was actually somewhat misleading, as there is nothing wrong with the way I've set up the test in the `if` element. [Here is the problem](http://dev.aviarc.com/docs/aviarc/reference/xml_commands/com.aviarc.base/1.3.0/if):

> Either the `<then>` or `<else>` sub-element can be omitted if no action is required under that condition.

The `if` command requires either one or both of `then` or `else` as its children. In this case, the command used as the body of the `if` was being treated as a condition, and the error is due to it not having a (boolean) return value.

This works:

```xml
<if test="equal" value1="{$m.parent_id}" value2="{$var.tasks-menu-id}">
    <then>
        <math:increment field="var.tasks-children"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

Comment: It isn't an error to have neither a then block nor an else block, it just isn't very useful (unless the test has a side-effect). The error is that the command which was intended for a then block was instead set as the if condition. On the one hand it would be useful if there was a conditions block added for non-inline conditions, on the other hand that would mean more indenting.

Comment: @TristanWilkinson thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly.